# Store current region 3d

Tags: python

I have to store the current region 3d for an object in a Python addon.

```
context.space_data.region_3d
```

But I have to create a copy of this, I dont want to store a reference, is this possible?

I need the location and rotation of the viewport when this object is created, so that I can manipulate it with the data of this, even when the user changes the current view zoom or rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got it, just copied the required info I needed

```
class ViewContext():

    def __init__(self, context):
        rv3d           = context.space_data.region_3d
        self._view_rot = rv3d.view_rotation.copy()
        self._view_mat = rv3d.view_matrix.copy()
        self._pers_mat = rv3d.perspective_matrix.copy()
        self._view_pers = rv3d.view_perspective
        self._is_perspective = rv3d.is_perspective
        self._region = ViewRegion(context.region)
```